# How To Apply Regex in Shiny App Filter/Button?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm super new to Shiny Apps and to R. How would I add a button that allows me to filter the passed-in dataset using this regex? The uploaded dataset would all contain the same column names, and the column I want to apply the regex to is "close_notes". I want to first **convert this column to a string, uppercase everything, then apply the regex**. Thank you so much for your help in advance!

The Regular Expression:

`"\\bMASTER DATA\\b|\\bSOURCE LIST\\b|\\bVALIDITY DATES\\b|\\bMRP CONTROLLER\\b|\\bPSV\\b|\\bELIGIBILITY\\b|\\bCOST\\b|\\bMARKETING EXCLUSION\\b|\\bEFFECTIVITY\\b|\\bMISSING\\b|\bbBLANK\\b"`

The code below is for the Shiny App. Please let me know if anything looks wrong or like it should be modified. Thank you!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                      accept = c(
                          "text/csv",
                          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                          ".csv")
            ),
            tags$hr(),
            checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
            
            # Button
            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
            
        ),
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput("contents")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    datasetInput <- reactive({
        req(input$file1)
        # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
        # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
        # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
        # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
        # be found.
        inFile <- input$file1
        
        if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)
        
        read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    })
    
    output$contents <- renderDataTable({
        datasetInput()
    })
    
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("myfile",Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some changes to your current code.

- Used `reactiveValues` to save the data uploaded, also changed `reactive` to `observe`.
- Added an `actionButton` to apply filter after pressing the button and used `observeEvent` on the server side.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

#Define the regex to apply. 
regex_to_apply <- "\\bMASTER DATA..."

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      
      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
      actionButton('apply_regex', 'Apply Regex')
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    req(input$file1)
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    rv$data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderDataTable({
    rv$data
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("myfile",Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(rv$data, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$apply_regex, {
    rv$data <- rv$data %>%  filter(grepl(regex_to_apply, toupper(close_notes)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the word boundaries to the outsides of the alternation, like this:

```regex
\b(MASTER DATA|SOURCE LIST|VALIDITY DATES|MRP CONTROLLER|PSV|ELIGIBILITY|COST|MARKETING EXCLUSION|EFFECTIVITY|MISSING|BLANK)\b
```

Comment: I do want to capture what is inside, so the regex I have is correct. How would I add this to my Shiny App? Thank you!